# How to convert totality of days, into number of years, months, and days (≤ 31)?

Tags: microsoft-office

Can MS Office instantly convert, e.g. 2782 days into _ years, _ months, _ days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Microsoft excel you can use the following formula (data in A2):

```
=DATEDIF(0,A2,"y")&" years, " &DATEDIF(0,A2,"ym")&" months, "&DATEDIF(0,A2,"md")&" days"
```

Using `2782` the result would be "7 years, 7 months, 13 days".

---

The number of months and years will be different depending on the starting date. If that is a concern, it is possible to specify a date to start from. In the formula above that date is `0/0/0` but it can easily be changed depending on the requirement; simply change the first parameter value of the `DATEDIF` for year, month and day, respectivly.

Comment: But the real answer depends on the choice of starting date, 0/0/0 in your code, because the length of months and years is variable (and, perhaps less importantly, also because of calendar changes)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: That is true. I added some relevant information to the answer of how to take that into account.